# Match <h1> text and <option> text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to look at the text in the `H1` and if it matches the text of one of the `<option>` it sets that option as selected.
The is what I am using to do this.

```
// Form selections
if ($("h1.entry-title").text() === "Bowed Front Outdoor Mirror") {
   $('select#input_5_5').val('Bowed Front Outdoor Mirror');
}
if ($("h1.entry-title").text() === "Scrolled Gate outdoor mirror") {
   $('select#input_5_5').val('Scrolled Gate outdoor mirror');
}
if ($("h1.entry-title").text() === "Scrolled Gate outdoor mirror large") {
   $('select#input_5_5').val('Scrolled Gate outdoor mirror large');
}
if ($("h1.entry-title").text() === "Two Tile design iron mirror") {
   $('select#input_5_5').val('Two Tile design iron mirror');
}
```

Basically a long list of if statements. Doesn't seem like a very efficient way to handle it.
If anyone can help me out to write this a bit smarter it would be great.
Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the text and the value are the same, you can just call

```
$('#input_5_5').val($("h1.entry-title").text());
```

Comment: I knew there was a much easier way. Thanks